# C++: Should class own or observe its dependencies?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, smart-pointer

Say I have a class `Foobar` that uses (depends on) class `Widget`. In good ol' days, `Widget` wolud be declared as a field in `Foobar`, or maybe as a smart pointer if polymorphic behavior was needed, and it would be initialized in constructor:

```
class Foobar {
    Widget widget;
    public:
    Foobar() : widget(blah blah blah) {}
    // or
    std::unique_ptr<Widget> widget;
    public:
    Foobar() : widget(std::make_unique<Widget>(blah blah blah)) {}
    (…)
};
```

And we'd be all set and done. Unfortunately, today, Java kids will laugh at us once they see it, and rightfully, as it couples `Foobar` and `Widget` together. The solution is seemingly simple: apply Dependency Injection to take construction of dependencies out of `Foobar` class. But then, C++ forces us to think about ownership of dependencies. Three solutions come to mind:

### Unique pointer

```
class Foobar {
    std::unique_ptr<Widget> widget;
    public:
    Foobar(std::unique_ptr<Widget> &&w) : widget(w) {}
    (…)
}
```

`Foobar` claims sole ownership of `Widget` that is passed to it. This has following advantages:

1. Impact on performance is negligible.
2. It's safe, as `Foobar` controls lifetime od its `Widget`, so it makes sure that `Widget` doesn't suddenly disappear.
3. It's safe that `Widget` won't leak and will be properly destructed when no longer needed.

However, this comes at a cost:

1. It places restrictions on how `Widget` instances can be used, e.g. no stack-allocated `Widgets` can be used, no `Widget` can be shared.

### Shared pointer

```
class Foobar {
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> widget;
    public:
    Foobar(const std::shared_ptr<Widget> &w) : widget(w) {}
    (…)
}
```

This is probably closest equivalent ot Java and other garbage collected languages. Advantages:

1. More universal, as it allows sharing dependencies.
2. Maintains safety (points 2 and 3) of `unique_ptr` solution.

Disadvantages:

1. Wastes resources when no sharing is involved.
2. Still requires heap allocation and disallows stack-allocated objects.

### Plain ol' observing pointer

```
class Foobar {
    Widget *widget;
    public:
    Foobar(Widget *w) : widget(w) {}
    (…)
}
```

Place raw pointer inside class and shift the burden of ownership to someone else. Pros:

1. As simple as it can get.
2. Universal, accepts just any `Widget`.

Cons:

1. Not safe anymore.
2. Introduces another entity that is responsible for ownership of both `Foobar` and `Widget`.

### Some crazy template metaprogramming

The only advantage I can think of is that I'd be able to read all those books I didn't find time for while my software is builing;)

I lean towards the third solution, as it is most universal, something has to manage `Foobars` anyway, so managing `Widgets` is simple change. However, using raw pointers bothers me, on the other hand smart pointer solution feel wrong to me, as they make consumer of dependency restrict how that dependency is created.

Am I missing something? Or is just Dependency Injection in C++ not trivial? Should class own its dependencies or just observe them?

Comment: Right from the start, if you can compile under C++11 and/or never, having plain pointer as a way to handle resources in a class is not the recommended way anymore. If the Foobar class is the only owner of the resource and the resource should be freed, when Foobar goes out of scope, `std::unique_ptr` is the way to go. You can use `std::move()` to transfer the ownership of a resource from upper scope to the class.

Comment: How I know that `Foobar` is the only owner? In the old case it's simple. But the problem with DI, as I see it, is as it decouples class from construction of its dependencies, it also decouples it from ownership of those dependencies (as ownership is tied to construction). In garbage collected environments such as Java, that's not a problem. In C++, this is.

Comment: @el.pescado There is also the same problem in Java, memory isn't the only resource. There is also files and connections for example. The usual way to solve this in Java is to have a container that manages the lifecycle of all its contained objects. Therefore you don't have to worry about it in the objects contained in a DI container. This could also work for c++ applications if there is a way for the DI container to know when to switch to which lifecycle phase.

Comment: Of course, you could do it the old-fashioned way without all the complexity and have code that works and is way easier to maintain. (Note that the Java boys may laugh, but they are always going on about refactoring, so decoupling isn't exactly helping them much)

Comment: Plus having other people laugh at you is not a reason for being like them. Listen to their arguments (other than "because we were told to") and implement DI if it brings tangible benefit to your project. In this case, think of the pattern as a very general rule, which you have to apply in a way that is specific to the project - all three approaches (and all other potential approaches which you haven't thought of yet) are valid given they bring an overall benefit (i.e. have more upsides than downsides).

Comment: Of course, I'm not going to do DI for the sake of doing DI or just to look cool. DI greatly helps testability, among others, which I find highly valuable.

Comment: "Say I have a class Foobar that uses (depends on) class Widget. In good ol' days, Widget wolud be declared as a field in Foobar" - NO. This is not how objects work. You would declare a field in Foobar *of type* Widget, in C++, if you want every `Foobar` to have *an instance of* `Widget` *with the particular lifetime properties that implies*. You would *not* say "Oh, `Foobar` uses `Widget` so I'll declare a `Widget` field in `Foobar`" because that won't actually help you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an observing pointer in the form of a reference. It gives a much better syntax when you use it and the has the semantic advantage that it doesn't imply ownership, which a plain pointer can.

The biggest problem with this approach is lifetimes. You have to ensure that the dependency is constructed before, and destructed after your depending class. It isn't a simple problem. Using shared pointers (as dependency storage and in all classes that depend on it, option 2 above) can remove this problem, but also introduces the problem of circular dependencies which is also non-trivial, and in my opinion less obvious and therefore harder to detect before it causes problems. Which is why I prefer to not do it automatically and manually manage the lifetimes and construction order. I've also seen systems that use a light template approach which constructed a list of objects in the order they were created and destroyed them in opposite order, it wasn't foolproof, but it made things a lot simpler.

### Update

David Packer's response made me think a little more about the question. The original answer is true for shared dependencies in my experience, which is one of the advantages of dependency injection, you can have multiple instances using the one instance of a dependency. If however your class needs to have it's own instance of a particular dependency then `std::unique_ptr` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

**I meant to write this as a comment, but it turned out to be too long.**

> How I know that `Foobar` is the only owner? In the old case it's simple. But the problem with DI, as I see it, is as it decouples class from construction of its dependencies, it also decouples it from ownership of those dependencies (as ownership is tied to construction). In garbage collected environments such as Java, that's not a problem. In C++, this is.

Whether you should use `std::unique_ptr<Widget>` or `std::shared_ptr<Widget>`, that is up to you to decide and comes from your functionality.

Let's assume you have a `Utilities::Factory`, which is responsible for the creation of your blocks, such as `Foobar`. Following the DI principle, you will need the `Widget` instance, to inject it using `Foobar`'s constructor, meaning inside one of the `Utilities::Factory`'s method, for example `createWidget(const std::vector<std::string>& params)`, you create the Widget and inject it into the `Foobar` object.

Now you have a `Utilities::Factory` method, which created the `Widget` object. Does it mean, the method should me responsible for its deletion? Of course not. It is only there to make you the instance.

---

Let's imagine, you are developing an application, which will have multiple windows. Each window is represented using the `Foobar` class, so in fact the `Foobar` acts like a controller.

The controller will probably make use of some of your `Widget`s and you have to ask yourself:

*If I go on this specific window in my application, I will need these Widgets. Are these widgets shared among other application windows? If so, I shouldn't be probably creating them all over again, because they will always look the same, because they are shared.*

`std::shared_ptr<Widget>` is the way to go.

You also have an application window, where there is a `Widget` specifically tied to this one window only, meaning it won't be displayed anywhere else. So if you close the window, you don't need the `Widget` anywhere in your application anymore, or at least its instance.

That's where `std::unique_ptr<Widget>` comes to claim its throne.

---

**Update:**

I don't really agree with *@DominicMcDonnell*, about the lifetime issue. Calling `std::move` on `std::unique_ptr` completely transfers the ownership, so even if you create an `object A` in a method and pass it to another `object B` as a dependency, the `object B` will now be responsible for the resource of `object A` and will correctly delete it, when `object B` goes out of scope.

Comment: The general idea of ownership and smart pointers is clear to me. It just doesn't seem to me to play nice with the idea of DI. Dependency Injection is, to me, about decoupling class from its dependencies, yet in this case class still influences how its dependencies are created.

Comment: For example, the problem I have with `unique_ptr` is unit testing (DI is advertised as testing-friendly): I want to test `Foobar`, so I create `Widget`, pass it to `Foobar`, exercise `Foobar` and then I want to inspect `Widget`, but unless `Foobar` somehow exposes it, I can't since it has been claimed by `Foobar`.

Comment: @el.pescado You are mixing two things together. You are mixing accessibility and ownership. Just because `Foobar` owns the resource does not mean, nobody else should use it. You could implement a `Foobar` method such as `Widget* getWidget() const { return this->_widget.get(); }`, which will return you the raw pointer you can work with. You can then use this method as an input for your unit tests, when you want to test the `Widget` class.

Comment: Good point, that makes sense.

Comment: @el.pescado The whole point of smart pointers is to make you forget about the `delete`. If you use smart pointers correctly and in a way your app requires them, unless you need some really low level optimization, you should see close to none `delete` calls throughout your application. So be careful, if you did something like this `Widget* widgetRaw = FooBarObject.getWidget();` and then called `delete widgetRaw;`, you would be breaking the encapsulation.

Comment: What bugs me, however, is that as it is possible to convert `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` but not the other way round, the rule should be that class should accept `shared_ptr` by default unless it's certain that dependency cannot be shared, which is opposite of general smart pointer rule ("use `unique_ptr` by default").

Comment: If you converted a shared_ptr to a unique_ptr, how would you want to guarantee unique_ness???

Answer (score 1):

You ignored a fourth possible answer, which combines the first code you posted (the "good ol' days" of storing a member by value) with dependency injection:

```
class Foobar {
    Widget widget;
public:
    Foobar(Widget w) // pass w by value
     : widget{ std::move(w) } {}
};
```

Client code can then write:

```
Widget w;
Foobar f1{ w }; // default: copy w into f1
Foobar f2{ std::move(w) }; // move w into f2
```

Representing the coupling between objects should not be done (purely) on the criteria you listed (that is, not based purely on "which is better for safe lifetime management").

You can also use conceptual criteria ("a car has four wheels" vs. "a car uses four wheels which the driver has to bring along").

You can have criteria imposed by other APIs (if what you get from an API is a custom wrapper or a std::unique_ptr for example, the options in your client code are limited as well).

Comment: This precludes polymorphic behavior, which severely limits added value.

Comment: True. I just thought to mention it since it is the form I end up using the most (I only use inheritance in my coding for polymorphic behavior - not code reuse, so I don't have many cases of needing polymorphic behavior)..

Answer (score 1):

First of all - this is C++, **not** Java - and here many things go differently. The Java people do not have those problems about ownership as there is automatic garbage collection that solves those for them.

Second: There is no general answer to this question - it depends on what the requirements are!

What is the problem about coupling FooBar and Widget? FooBar wants to use a Widget, and if every FooBar instance always will have its own and the same Widget anyway, leave it coupled...

In C++, you can even do "weird" things that simply do not exist in Java, e. g. have a variadic template constructor (well, there exists a ... notation in Java, which can be used in constructors, too, but that is just syntactic sugar to hide an object array, which actually has nothing to do with real variadic templates!) - category 'Some crazy template metaprogramming':

```cpp
namespace WidgetFactory
{
    Widget* create(int, int)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    Widget* create(int, bool, long)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
class FooBar
{
public:
    template < typename ...Arguments >
    FooBar(Arguments... arguments)
        : mWidget(WidgetFactory::create(arguments...))
    {
    }
    ~FooBar()
    {
        delete mWidget;
    }
private:
    Widget* mWidget;
};

FooBar foobar1(10, 12);
FooBar foobar2(51, true, 54L);
```

Like it?

Of course, there **are** reasons when you want or need to decouple both classes - e. g. if you need to create the widgets at a time far before any FooBar instance exists, if you want or need to reuse the widgets, ..., or simply because for the current problem it is more appropriate (e. g. if Widget is a GUI element and FooBar shall/can/must not be one).

Then, we get back to the second point: No general answer. You need to decide, what - for the **actual** problem - is the more appropriate solution. I like DominicMcDonnell's reference approach, but it can only be applied if ownership shall not be taken by FooBar (well, actually, you could, but that implies very, very dirty code...). Apart from that, I join David Packer's answer (the one meant to be written as comment - but a good answer, anyway).

Comment: In C++, don't use `class`es with nothing but static methods, even if it's just a factory as in your example. That violates the OO principles. Use namespaces instead and group your functions using them.

Comment: @DavidPacker Hmm, sure, you're right - I silently assumed the class to have some private internals, but that's neither visible nor mentioned elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing at least two more options that are available to you in C++:

One is to use 'static' dependency injection where your dependencies are template parameters. This gives you the option of holding your dependencies by value while still allowing compile time dependency injection. STL containers use this approach for allocators and comparison and hash functions for example.

Another is to take polymorphic objects by value using a deep copy. The traditional way to do this is using a virtual clone method, another option that's become popular is to use type erasure to make value types that behave polymorphically.

Which option is most appropriate really depends on your use case, it's hard to give a general answer. If you only need static polymorphism though I'd say templates are the most C++ way to go.